# Who is Naqib in Sahih al-Bukhari 18?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

[Sahih al-Bukhari 18](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/11):

> who took part in the battle of Badr and was a **Naqib** (a person heading
> a group of six persons), on the night of Al-'Aqaba pledge:
> ...

So the Hadith itself is defining it as **"a person heading a group of six persons"**. But it is not clear who are these six persons, why Naqib should be their head, what is the purpose of this 7-person community and what is their importance in Islam.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naqib#:%7E:text=Naqib%2C%20plural%20naqib%2C%20is%20an,He%20who%20investigates%2C%20verifies%22.):

> Naqib, plural naqib, is an Arabic word meaning "He who investigates,
> verifies". It can refer to:
>
> 1. The "twelve naqibs", the leading missionaries of the Hashimiyya movement who prepared the Abbasid Revolution in Khurasan.
> 2. The naqib al-ashraf, an honorary position in various Islamic states, given to the head representative of the ashraf, the
>    descendants of Muhammad.

Again there is definition and no clarification in details.

**So, who is Naqib in the context of Sahih al-Bukhari 18?**

Comment: The wikipedia site certainly is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naqib is a title which means leader or representative, as used in the Quran in [5:12](https://quran.com/5/12). In this hadith it refers to the narrator **Ubadah bin As-Samit**, who was among those who gave the Pledge of al-Aqabah to the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ from the people of Medinah. You should consult a book on [seerah](https://archive.org/details/TheSealedNectar_201501/page/n159/mode/2up) for details.

Comment: What can you say regarding Wikipedia information?

Comment: It is not wrong, however it is not complete and it is not relevant to the hadith as the Abbasid revolution and Islamic states came long after the events of this hadith.

Comment: The seerah you gave link to has become unavailable. Is there an alternative link?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/TheSealedNectar-Alhamdulillah-library.blogspot.in.pdf/page/n9/mode/2up

Answer (score 0):

This hadith refers to the events of the First Aqabah. That is when 12 people from the people of Madinah (Yathrib at the time) came to Makkah to pledge allegiance to the Prophet (SAW) and Islam.

Ubada ibn As-Samit is referred to as "one of the Nuqaba." Nuqaba is the plural for Naqeeb. Naqeeb means a "representative," "watcher," or "leader."

In this context, these 12 people are all referred to as Nuqaba because they came to represent Madinah or perhaps because they were sent to represent Islam to their people.

Perhaps a better translation might be:

> Narrated 'Ubada bin As-Samit: who took part in the battle of Badr, and was one of the representatives (Nuqaba) on the night of Al-'Aqaba pledge [...]

Honestly, I don't understand what the translator meant with "a person heading a group of six persons."